# Returning an array of inserted sequence values

Tags: postgresql

I have an insert statement that may insert single or multiple records into a table with an INSERT statement. I need to know what the primary id value is for each new row.

Tried adding the following to the insert statement:

```
RETURNING array_agg(new_seq_id) INTO new_ids
```

Get the following error:

```
[42803] ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in RETURNING
```

Is there a way to get an array into the returning statements of all the new sequence values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).

```sql
with t as
(
  -- your insert statement
  RETURNING new_seq_id
) 
select array_agg(new_seq_id) from t into new_ids;
```

Answer (score 2):

After returning newly generated (and actually inserted!) IDs in a data-modifying CTE (like others provided), to insert into a table, you need an `INSERT` statement:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   INSERT ...
   RETURNING new_seq_id
   )
INSERT INTO tbl(new_ids)
SELECT ARRAY(TABLE cte)
```

`TABLE cte` is the short form of `SELECT * FROM cte`.

An ARRAY constructor is typically a bit faster than the (more versatile) `array_agg()` aggregate function. See:

- [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/159717/3684)

Only makes sense if you, indeed, need to return a single array. You might just return a *set* of rows with the `RETURNING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it into a common table expression:

```
with new_rows as (
  insert into (...)
  values (...)
  returning new_seq_id
)
select array_agg(new_seq_id)
  into new_ids
from new_rows;
```